langchain: how to prevent the language model response from being prefixed with AI: or Assistant:
I have the following langchain prompt setup for a RAG based chat application:
## Prompt Chain Setup ##
retrieval_qa_chat_prompt = hub.pull("langchain-ai/retrieval-qa-chat")
retriever = chroma_db.as_retriever()

contextualize_q_system_prompt = (
    "Given a chat history and the latest user question "
    "which might reference context in the chat history, "
    "formulate a standalone question which can be understood "
    "without the chat history. Do NOT answer the question, "
    "just reformulate it if needed and otherwise return it as is."
)

contextualize_q_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", contextualize_q_system_prompt),
        #MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"), <- removed to stop question_generator
        ("human", "{input}"),
    ]
)
history_aware_retriever = create_history_aware_retriever(
    llm, retriever, contextualize_q_prompt
)


system_prompt = (
    "Use the following pieces of retrieved context to answer "
    "the question. If you don't know the answer, say that you "
    "don't know. Keep the answer concise and ensure that any"
    "configuration file samples or examples use JSON format."
    "\n\n"
    "{context}"
)

qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", system_prompt),
        MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
        ("human", "{input}"),
    ]
)
question_answer_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, qa_prompt)

rag_chain = create_retrieval_chain(history_aware_retriever, question_answer_chain)

and I'm talking to the microsoft/Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct-gguf model via LM Studio locally with default settings using the local server.
For some reason every response from the LLM is prefixed with 'Assistant:' or 'AI:' which is redundant for me, as the user interface will clearly show which text/content is from the AI versus the human messages (think iPhone SMS chat).
How can I remove this? I've tried coaching the prompt to do it, but it makes no difference asking the model not to put this prefix in.
Example response:
AI: The "isRequired" field indicates whether or not a form field must be filled out for the form to be submitted. If set to true.....

Have you considered writing a regex to replace ^(AI|Assistant): ? with ""?

Hey Nick, I have, but consider that as a last resort, 1) because it's streaming the result, so there's trickiness I assume in regex on a stream, unless I get the result from the LLM in one go, regex, then stream and 2) Occurrences of the word elsewhere in the response could create confusion. I was hoping there was a langchain/llm/prompt engineering friendly way of controlling the behaviour.
